# save text to default Notes app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on app in which there is a textview with save button. On the click of save button I suppose to open the Notes app and save the text on notes. Same as we done to post the sms. 
I also go through this given pdf file [iPhoneURLScheme_Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference.pdf)

But didn't find out the way to save the text/open the notes app from the app. If  someone has ever done this type of functionality or having some idea please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't expect there to be an URL scheme if it is not present in the PDF you linked to.
I wold expect it to be on [this list](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes) however.

Looks like you can't do that.

If you consider the URL schemes in Apple's document you will notice that all of the schemes refer to an application the user is expected to interact with immediately (navigating with Maps, making a call,...). All these applications provide something you can't do your own. What would be the benefit of your app if it just allowed the user to write a note once?